# Auto-escaping yanked strings in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I apparently have a powerful itch this weekend to add a ton of functionality to my Emacs environment. I can do some basics on my own, and hunt down other stuff, but I haven't been able to find a solution to this (and am not good enough at Lisp to do it on my own).

I frequently work with strings of HTML, and sometimes if I move them from one block to another (or one language to another) strings are broken where they aren't escaped. So, I want a function that does something like this:

```
(defun smart-yank-in-string()
      (if (stringp) ; Check if the point is in a string
        ; Check if the region created from the point to the end of the yank ends the string 
        ; (and there is more yank left that isn't ";")
        ; Escape quotes for those locations recursively by prepending \
        ; Insert result into buffer @ mark
          ))
```

Any clever ideas? I *think* it involves using `kill-new` to stash a variable and walk through it, but I'm not conversant enough in elisp to solve it.

Comment: You're confusing mark with point it seems. Can you add a minimal example? Or check if http://abo-abo.github.io/lispy/#sec-3-25 is what you want.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, fixed it above. I meant point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next yank should insert the escaped string:

```
(defun escape-doublequotes-at-car-of-kill-ring ()
  "Escape doublequotes in car of kill-ring "
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert (car kill-ring))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\"" nil t 1)
      (replace-match "\\\\\""))
    (kill-new (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative

```
(defun my-yank()
  (interactive)
  (if (nth 3 (syntax-ppss)) ;; Checks if inside a string
      (insert-for-yank (replace-regexp-in-string "[\\\"]"
                                                 "\\\\\\&"
                                                 (current-kill 0)
                                                 t))
    (call-interactively 'yank)))
```

The command when invoked checks if the point is in a string, if so it escapes the yanked text otherwise it yanks normally. One disadvantage is that you cannot use `yank-pop` after yanking inside a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it as follow (guaranteed 100% non-functional code ahead):

```
(defun my-kill-quoted-string (start end)
  "Like kill-region but takes of unquoting/requoting."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((str (buffer-extract-substring start end)))
    (if (nth 3 (syntax-ppss))
        ;; Unquote according to mode and context.  E.g. we should unquote &quot; and things like that in HTML.
        (setq str (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\\"" "\"" str)))
    (put-text-property 0 (length str) 'yank-handler
                       (list (lambda (str)
                               (if (not (nth 3 (syntax-ppss)))
                                   (insert str)
                                 ;; Requote according to mode and context.
                                 (insert (replace-regexp-in-string "[\\\"]" "\\\\\\&" str))))))
    (kill-new str)))
```